# Replace New lines to space in matches with regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm working on a Powershell script where I'm trying to edit a logfile. The logfile has the following pattern. I selected a 3 line package with the following regex:
`\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\sra-agi\sTrace:.*\n){3}(?=\n)`

```
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf

11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
```

Now i would like to have these three lines on one line --> remove the new lines. It should look like the following image. so i got the three lines in one line and a empty line between the data lines.

```
11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf

11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf

11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace: asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf 11:20:36:645 ra-agi Trace:     asdfaa adfadaf dafadfsd adfdsfa dafsdfa dafsdfa dafdsf
```

I tried it  with the following code sadly its doesnt work:

```
$filteredLog -replace '(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\sra-agi\sTrace:.*\n){3}(?=\n)', '(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\sra-agi\sTrace:.*\s){3}(?=\n)'  > newline.txt
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could solve it?
Thanks guys for your help in advance

Comment: Please do add actual outputs rather than adding screenshots.

Comment: Note that you need to use `-Raw` option when reading in the file to expose newlines to the regex.

Comment: Or use `Select-String -Path path\to\log.file`

Comment: Without using Regex it's easier. Should I post a solution, @fbe106360?

Comment: yes if i dont need to regex then go on ;) @WasifHasan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're joining every three lines:

```
get-content file -ReadCount 3 | foreach { $_ -join ' ' } 

one two three
four five six
```